# Table join sql to rails active record query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

How can I convert the following into an active record query:

```
SELECT reviews.style_id, AVG("col1"), AVG("col2")
  FROM reviews, audios
 WHERE reviews.consumer_id = audios.consumer_id
 GROUP BY style_id;
```

`col1` and `col2` belong to the audios table, but they are uniquely named (no similar column name in `reviews`), so there is no ambiguity error.

I am using PostgreSQL.

Comment: Why convert, execute it as a raw sql

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have an association between `Review` and `Audio` then something like this:

```
revs = Review.joins(:audios)
             .group('style_id')
             .select('style_id, avg(col1) as avg_col1, avg(col2) as avg_col2')
```

That will give a list of `Review` instances in `revs` and those instances will have extra `avg_col1` and `avg_col2` methods for accessing the averages as well as the usual `style`/`style_id` methods but the other column accessor methods that `Review` would normally offer will raise exceptions.

If you don't have the associations set up then you can do the JOIN manually:

```
revs = Review.joins('join audios on reviews.consumer_id = audios.consumer_id')
             .group('style_id')
             .select('style_id, avg(col1) as avg_col1, avg(col2) as avg_col2')
```

If all you need is just the raw data without all the ActiveRecord wrapping and overhead, then you could execute the raw SQL and hashify it by hand using [`select_rows`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/DatabaseStatements.html#method-i-select_rows):

```
Review.connection.select_rows(%q{
    select r.style_id, avg(a.col1), avg(a.col2')
    from reviews r
    join audios  a on r.consumer_id = a.consumer_id
    group by r.style_id
}).map do
  { :style_id => r.shift, :avg_col1 => r.shift.to_f, :avg_col2 => r.shift.to_f }
end
```

That would give you an Array of Hashes. You could even simplify that approach using [`Struct`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Struct.html) to create simple data wrapper classes:

```
c    = Struct.new(:style_id, :avg_col1, :avg_col2)
revs = Review.connection.select_rows(%q{...}).map do |r|
  c.new(r.shift, r.shift.to_f, r.shift.to_f)
end
```

PS: Don't use implicit join conditions your SQL, that's just a quick and easy way to produce cross products, use explicit join conditions:

```
SELECT ...
  FROM reviews JOIN audios ON reviews.consumer_id = audios.consumer_id
 GROUP BY style_id
```

Comment: Mu, do you know of any good tutorials for advanced active record queries. I'd like to learn more. Thanks

Comment: @Abram: There's the [Active Record Query Interface Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html), I don't know of anything better than that off the top of my header. I used the guide and a lot of playing around in the Rails console to learn this stuff; having strong SQL-fu helps of course.

Comment: By the way looks like the active record method is .joins, not .join  .. either way, super helpful.. I've managed to achieve some amazing stuff thanks to your post. Cheers

Comment: @Abram: Right, thanks for pointing out the typos, sorry about that. They're both fixed now.