# Display latest messages from messages table, group by user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to create an inbox for messaging between users.
Here are the following tables:

```
Messsages
Id | Message_from | message_to | message
1  | 2            |   1        | Hi
2  | 2            |   1        | How are you
3  | 1            |   3        | Hola
4  | 4            |   1        | Whats up
5  | 1            |   4        | Just Chilling
6  | 5            |   1        | Bonjour

Users
Id | Name
1  | Paul
2  | John
3  | Tim
4  | Rob
5  | Sarah
6  | Jeff
```

I'd like to display an inbox showing the list of users that the person has communicated and the last_message from either users

Paul's Inbox:

```
Name | user_id | last_message
Sarah| 5       | bonjour
Rob  | 4       | Just Chilling
Tim  | 3       | Hola
John | 2       | How are you
```

How do I do this with Active Records?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be rather efficient:

```
SELECT u.name, sub.*
FROM  (
   SELECT DISTINCT ON (1)
          m.message_from AS user_id
        , m.message AS last_message
   FROM   users    u
   JOIN   messages m ON m.message_to = u.id
   WHERE  u.name = 'Paul'   -- must be unique
   ORDER  BY 1, m.id DESC
   ) sub
JOIN  users u ON sub.user_id = u.id;
```

Compute all users with the latest message in the subquery `sub` using `DISTINCT ON`. Then join to 
table `users` a second time to resolve the name.

Details for `DISTINCT ON`:
[Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

Aside: Using "id" and "name" as column names is not a very helpful naming convention.

Comment: Great! Thanks Erwin. How do I do this in Active Records please

Comment: @user3649729: You could use raw SQL like explained by mu in this related answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10633412/table-join-sql-to-rails-active-record-query/10639918#10639918

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
@received_messages = current_user.messages_to.order(created_at: :desc).uniq
```

If you want to include messages from the user as well, you might have to do a union query, or two queries, then merge and join them. I'm just guessing with some pseudocode, here, but this should set you on your way.

```
received_messages = current_user.messages_to
sent_messages = current_user.messages_from
(received_messages + sent_messages).sort_by { |message| message[:created_at] }.reverse
```

This type of logic is belongs to a model, not the controller, so perhaps you can add this to the `message` model.

Comment: @user3649729 ahhh.. that's a bit more tricky... let me think about it for bit!

Comment: @user3649729 since you are using the same table, you might be able to do some type of union query, or two queries, then merge and sort the results...

Comment: The issue there is that once I join the two queries. I cannot sort the result. Thanks again!

Comment: @user3649729 I took out the code. It was wrong... See my earlier two comments.

Comment: So you could please advise on how I can "do some type of union query, or two queries, then merge and sort the results." thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
scope :ids_of_latest_per_user, -> { pluck('MAX(id)').group(:user_id) }
scope :latest_per_user,        -> { where(:id => Message.latest_by_user) }

Message.latest_per_user
```