# Get a list of first record for each group

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, greatest-n-per-group

I have a `Log` model with following columns:

```
["id", "username", "event", "parameters", "extras", "created_at", "updated_at"]
```

I have indexes `created_at` and `username`.
Now, I would like to get the first log for each `username` ordered by `created_at`.

One way to do this is to run the following query for each username:

```
log = Log.where("username = :username", username: username).order(:created_at).first
```

But this obviously queries the database a lot of times (equal to the number of usernames). Is there some way to do only one database query?

Comment: It is important to set ONE index on 2 columns, a.g.: "add_index :logs, [:username, :created_at]". If you have indexes for each columns alone, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another case for `DISTINCT ON`:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ON (username) *
FROM   log
ORDER  BY username, created_at;
```

Returns *the whole row* for the "first" entry per `username`.

Details:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

Similar answer for Ruby / AR / Postgres:

- [Display latest messages from messages table, group by user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23728320/display-latest-messages-from-messages-table-group-by-user/23728690#23728690)

How to execute raw SQL:

- [Table join sql to rails active record query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10633412/table-join-sql-to-rails-active-record-query/10639918#10639918)

This Ruby syntax should work:

```rb
Log.select("DISTINCT ON (username) *").order(:username, :created_at)
```

Comment: @Peeyush: I added Ruby syntax.

Comment: I was able to figure that out :). Thanks for making the answer complete.

Answer (score 0):

`Log.select("DISTINCT username").order(:created_at)`

Comment: I don't want a list of usernames! I am interested in other columns (`parameters` and `extras`) for  first record in each group as mentioned in question.

Answer (score 0):

I think `group by` clause would do the trick.

```
Log.group(:username).order(:created_at)
```

This will give you a query like this:

```
SELECT `logs`.* from `logs` GROUP BY username ORDER BY `logs`.`created_at` ASC
```

which will return first record for each `username`.

Comment: It does not return the first log in PostgreSQL. I think it does so in MySQL. Thannx anyway. :)